# $T$ has a countable $\omega$-saturated models if and only if $\forall n |S_n(T)|\leq\omega$ (Hodges, ex. 6.2.6)

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, solution-verification, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am trying to solve the excercise in the title, here its text.
With $S_n(T)$ we denote complete $n$-types without parameters of the tehory $T$
[image]

Now $(a)\rightarrow (b)$ is clear to me. So I would try to prove $(a)\rightarrow (b)\rightarrow (c)\rightarrow(a)$.

Concerning $(c)\rightarrow (a)$, what I need to show is that there is a countable $A\in Mod(T)$ which is $\omega$-saturated, i.e.

> For any $L$-structure $B$, if $\bar{a},\bar{b}$ are n-tuples such that $(A,\bar{a})\equiv (B,\bar{b})$ and $d$ is any element of $B$ then there is $c$ in $A$ such that $(A,\bar{a},c)\equiv (B,\bar{b},d)$.

By $(A,\bar{a})\equiv (B,\bar{b})$  we know that $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ realize the same complete $n$ type in $A$ and $B$ respectively. What I would try to show is that, chosen $d\in B$, there is a $c\in A$ such that $\bar{a}c$ realizes the same $n+1$ complete type of $\bar{b}d$.
Under $(a)$ we know that $T$ has a countable atomic model, and I was trying to use this fact in order to get an $\omega$-saturated one. Anyway the only direction to which the existence of such a model leads seems to be the existence of a countable prime model, which is in some sense dual to that $\omega$-saturated. So I am stuck: $(c)$ seems to suggest the application of the countable omitting types theorem, but again I cannot figure how. Maybe the fact $T$ is countable plays a role too.

Sadly I have no idea about $(b)\rightarrow(c)$. Any idea about how to close?

More in generale what can we say about the relation between being an atomic model of a theory and being an $\omega$ saturated structure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For (b)->(c) such a model realizes every type that can be realized in a countable model, i.e. every type, so there can only be countably many types.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks! Do you believe c to a is correct?

Comment: No. I don't really understand the argument, though.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I edited. What I wrote had no sense

Comment: The usual argument for that part is to construct a countable saturated model as an elementary chain union. (Also, this is a saturated model... you don’t want to omit types, you want to realize them. Atomic = omit as much as possible, saturated = realize as much as possible... they’re opposites in this regard. )